# In worksheet, if a word is found in A5 cell then want to copy B5 cell value, using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

In Excel there are 2 columns with A and B value. If the word "courage" is found in A5 cell then I want to copy B5 cell value.

And if "courage" word is in A10 then copy B10 value (opposite cell). I have prepared the below script to find courage it is working correctly but unable to copy opposite cell value.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')
$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$WorkSheet.Name
$Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find('courage')

If ($Found.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out -

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\Book1.xlsx')
$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)
$column = 1
$LastRow = $workSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
for($row=1; $row -lt $LastRow; $row++)
{
    if ($WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, $column).Value2 -eq "courage")
    {
        $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, $column+1).Value2 = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($row, $column).Value2
    }
}
#Proceed with other operations
#else save the worksheet and workbook
#Quit excel after you are done
```

Comment: hi vivek my requirement is different for example. i have a 50 lists of stationery products in A column and for every product its price is written in B column . Now i want to search for any product and if found in A column then it simply copy the price value of a product from B column.  hope you understand sir  ............................                                                 Items Price..................................
Pencil 50
Colours 100
Rubber 20
Sharpner 30
scale 60

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52023598/edit) your question to add the details. Explain what you really want to achieve. You haven't included the details currently.

Comment: hi vivek below is the requirement details:  for example. i have a 50 lists of stationery products in A column and for every product its price is written in B column . Now i want to search for any product and if found in A column then it simply copy the price value of a product from B column. hope you understand sir ............................ Items Price.................................. Pencil 50 Colours 100 Rubber 20 Sharpner 30 scale 60